# How to extract nodes with PostGIS to a multipoint geometry

Tags: postgis, export, line, vertices, multipart

I have a line in a PostGIS table `test_line`. I want to extract it's nodes into a multipoint geometry.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT ST_Collect((ST_DumpPoints(the_geom)).geom) FROM test_line;
```

But it gives me the error `ERROR:  set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set`.

What do I have to change in order to get it to work?

Comment: I'm curious to know whether and how you want to scale up your test case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem and this mailing list post helped me:

http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-users/2010-June/026887.html

The solution they came up with is as follows:

```
SELECT gid, ST_AsText(replace(ST_AsEWKT(geom), 'LINESTRING',
'MULTIPOINT')::geometry)
FROM
 (SELECT 1 as gid, 'LINESTRING (0 0, 0 3, 3 4)'::geometry AS geom
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 as gid, 'LINESTRING (1 1, 2 6, 7 7)'::geometry AS geom) AS g;
```

Answer (score 1):

`ST_Dump` is returning multiple values for one row, which cannot be nested within the `ST_Collect()` function, so you must separate things out using a sub-query.

```
 SELECT ST_Collect(the_geom2) 
 FROM (
       SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(the_geom)).geom AS the_geom2 
       FROM test_line) foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but this worked for me:

```
WITH A AS (
  SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(the_geom)).geom
  FROM test_line
)
SELECT ST_Collect(geom) FROM A;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we should use [ST_Points](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Points.html) for this.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Points(ST_MakeLine(ST_Point(0,0),ST_Point(1,1))))
```